# using sed to edit /etc/fstab

Tags: bash, sed

/etc/fstab line I want to edit:

```
/dev/appvg/home         /home     ext3    defaults        0 0
```

How do I get sed to insert ",nodev" behind the defaults column?

I found this command in another post that inserts it before "defaults", and I can't figure out how get to insert after:

```
sed -ie 's:\(.*\)\(\s/home\s\s*\)\(\w*\s*\)\(\w*\s*\)\(.*\):\1\2\3nodev,\4\5:' /etc/fstab
```

which gives me this:

```
/dev/appvg/home         /home     ext3    nodev,defaults  0 0
```

This is how I want it to look like:

```
/dev/appvg/home         /home     ext3    defaults,nodev  0 0
```

Is it possible?  I'm new to sed...

Answer (score 5):

The simplest answer to your question, assuming that this is exactly what you want to change is:

```
sed -ie '/^\/dev\/appvg\/home/ s/defaults/defaults,nodev/' /etc/fstab
```

What this says to do is to match the line starting (^) with ^/dev/appvg/home, and then apply the following command to it. In this case, the following command is "change defaults to defaults,nodev"

If you wanted to modify the command that you proposed to do the change, then you would want:

```
sed -ie 's:\(.*\)\s\(/home\)\s\s*\(\w*\)\s*\(\w*\)\s*\(.*\):\1 \2 \3 \4,nodev \5:' /etc/fstab
```

The \1, \2, etc between the last two ':' characters are replacement markers, and they say to replace the contents of the matching brackets from the first part of the expression. By changing where the \s are in the matching expression, then you only get the word (\w) characters and not the space (\s) characters in your substitution. Because of this, you need to insert your own spaces into the resulting string.

Comment: @BrianKuepper Glad it helped. Unfortunately, you will find it really hard to not mess the columns up. If it is critical that you keep the columns aligned, then you will need a significantly more complex program that will need to keep track of how long all of the lines are, and print the result to the right length. To do this, you probably want to look at using awk, and not sed.

Comment: @BrianKuepper As an aside, if this answer does solve your problem, don't forget to "accept" the answer.

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly...thx!!

Now on another system I have the same issue, but the command messes up the tabbed columns.

Here is the command I used:

sed -e '/^\/dev\/mapper\/system-home/ s/defaults/defaults,nodev/' /etc/fstab
 
Here is the output:

/dev/mapper/system-home /home                   ext4    defaults,nodev        1 2
/dev/mapper/system-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

(don’t know if it will show up right in the fourm)

Is there any way to replace the white space following defaults,nodev with a tab instead of multiple spaces?

Comment: I figured it out:  sed -e '/^\/dev\/mapper\/system-home/ s/defaults\s*1/defaults,nodev\t1/' /etc/fstab

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `awk`. Generally in Linux, `defaults` comes in the 4th column of the `/etc/fstab` file. You could use that to print only if the line has a `default` in it.

```
awk '/defaults/{$4="defaults,nodev"}{print}' /etc/fstab
```

To be specific to your case,

```
awk '/\/dev\/appvg\/home/{$4="defaults,nodev"}{print}' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: The `cat` is redundant, `awk` takes a filename as its input. Also, this doesn't *write* to `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way also:

```
sed "s*/opt/apps/app1               ext4    defaults        1 1*/opt            ext4    defaults        1 2*g" -i /etc/fstab
```

- from frist `*` to second `*`: string to be searched for
- from second `*` to third `*`: string to be replaced with.

you can first try without `-i` option which outputs changes on terminal but doesn't actually change in the actual file.